# mvc Javascript file not updating after changes in file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I have created one web application in `mvc`. I have added one **js** file in my project. On `_Layout.cshtml` page I have added this script.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My problem is if I do some changes in **main.js** file it is not reflecting after running the code. Browser is not updating the latest changes in script. To update the script I need to go to `C:\Users\Demo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache` and delete all the file from this folder. When I delete the files and refresh the page then the new changes is reflect. How can I avoid this? How can I update the script when there is changes?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP I used to add random numer to link, then the browser treat the file as different:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/main.js?number=random" type="text/javascript"></script>
```